# Uploading Files in php not working

Tags: php

Can anyone help me solve this problem of file upload in php. I am getting undefined index at line! The codes are in two seperate files. I tried several codes, still not working. Please help. Thank you all in advance.
HTML File

```
<form role="form" name="uploadPro" id="uploadPro" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
         <div class="form-group">
                <label>Product Tags</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" name="pTags" id="PTags"></textarea>
                <p class="help-block">Add Tags to your products to enable faster search.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
                <label>Product Expiry Date</label>
                 <input type="text" name="pExpDate" id="datepicker" class="form-control">
                <p class="help-block">Until which date will product be displayed.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
                <label>Upload Main Image</label>
                <input type="file" name="mainPath" id="mainPath">
                <p class="help-block">This image will appear everywhere. Make sure it has a good quality to impress users and size greater than 400px X 400px. </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
                <label>Upload Sub Image 1</label>
                <input type="file" name="sub1"  id="sub1">
                <p class="help-block">Make sure image has a good quality to impress users and size greater than 400px X 400px. </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
                <label>Upload Sub Image 2</label>
                <input type="file" name="sub2" id="sub2">
                <p class="help-block">Make sure image has a good quality to impress users and size greater than 400px X 400px. </p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
                <label>Upload Sub Image 3</label>
                <input type="file"  name="sub3" id="sub3">
                <p class="help-block">Make sure image has a good quality to impress users and size greater than 400px X 400px. </p>
          </div>

           <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">
    </div>

</form>
```

PHP Code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    /*Uploading main image*/
    $filetmp = $_FILES["mainPath"]["tmp_name"];//getting error here
    $filename = $_FILES["mainPath"]["name"];//getting error here
    $filepath = "../uploads/".$filename;
    move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $filepath);

    /*Uploading sub image1*/
    $filetmp1 = $_FILES["sub1"]["tmp_name"];//getting error here
    $filename1 = $_FILES["sub1"]["name"];//getting error here
    $filepath1 = "../uploads/".$filename1;
    move_uploaded_file($filetmp1, $filepath1);

    /*Uploading sub image2*/
    $filetmp2 = $_FILES["sub2"]["tmp_name"];//getting error here
    $filename2 = $_FILES["sub2"]["name"];//getting error here
    $filepath2 = "../uploads/".$filename2;
    move_uploaded_file($filetmp2, $filepath2);

    /*Uploading sub image3*/
    $filetmp3 = $_FILES["sub3"]["tmp_name"];//getting error here
    $filename3 = $_FILES["sub3"]["name"];//getting error here
    $filepath3 = "../uploads/".$filename3;
    move_uploaded_file($filetmp3, $filepath3);
}
```

Comment: what error you r getting??

Comment: What error you getting on which line?

Comment: see in my PHP code. i added comment //getting error here

Comment: Error: 
Undefined index mainPath
Undefined index sub1
Undefined index sub2
Undefined index sub3

Comment: No. am running the first page first and on submit click, upload.php is opened.
not working for me :(

Comment: Please give the all permission to your directory.Because your code is running on my localhost.

Comment: I tired a simple example. It was uploading correctly. This one is not working. I put this code in a template. you think javascipt or .js files are creating conflicts?

Comment: I have used this one also in my php code: if(isset($_FILES['image'])){...}
nothing happens.. where is the error?

Comment: ok, do one thing write `print_r($_FILES); die();` on the top of upload.php file and let me know what it returns, and tag me in the comment i can  get that u replied me, otherwise it will not notify me.

Comment: @KaushaMehta am getting this: Array ( )
I think file upload is not sending anything to uploads.php.
how can i solve this? Thanks

Comment: Try to write the same code in the file where is your form, write `print_r($_FILES); die();` before form tag and remove the action from form and let me know.

Comment: Its Working. i didnt change anything! i restarted my wamp server, and bow   its working. Thank you all for helping me though :)

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure that PHP is configured to allow file uploads.

In your "php.ini" file, search for the file_uploads directive, and set it to On:

```
file_uploads = On
```

[Error Messages Explained](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

PHP returns an appropriate error code along with the file array. The error code can be found in the error segment of the file array that is created during the file upload by PHP. In other words, the error might be found in $_FILES['userfile']['error'].

Comment: Its working. I tried a basic example first, image uploading in file correctly. But this one is not working. Trying to find solution since 2 days!
Thanks for your response :)

Comment: You could explain what changes you made so that other users with similar problem will find easy to fix.

Comment: i meant the first example i tried in uploading correctly(which mean file_uploads is on). This one is not working.

Answer (score 0):

First use `print_r($_FILES)` to check if the values r posting.

Use for loop instead of accessing index,

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

foreach ($_FILES as $row) {
     $filetmp = $row['tmp_name']; //getting error here
     $filename = $row["name"]; //getting error here
     $filepath = "../uploads/" . $filename;
     move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $filepath);
}
```

Comment: I have used this one also in my php code: if(isset($_FILES['image'])){...}
nothing happens.. where is the error?

Comment: file not uploading in folder uploads and nothing happens when upload.php runs! i think file upload is not sending anything! how to solve this issue?

Comment: No only a blank page.i think isset($_FILES['image']) has not been executed! hope u get my point.

Comment: `image` is not at all there, just check for isset of post of submit.

Comment: sorry, it is: if(isset($_FILES['mainPath']))

Answer (score 0):

I can check you code in my test file and its working file it may be issue is on your "php.ini" file. please send me your error so i can identify.

Comment: I changed the (isset($_POST['submit']) to if(isset($_FILES['mainPath'])){...}.
I am getting a blank page like nothing is executed, that is (isset($_FILES['image'])) has not occured. hope u get my point

Comment: @Student Are you checked on your folder "uploads" images upload or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I did not change anything. I restarted  my Wamp server and run the page in incognito window. Its working now.
Thank you all for your help. It makes me really happy to see how you help each other.